# react native asyncstorage how to save and add object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, store, asyncstorage

**I found this piece of code in one of the tutorials, as I understand it, when entering text inside the input, the text is saved in asyncstorage, but how to make that when the button is pressed, an object is formed and added to the state like thi**s `{id: 1, name: 'Alex'}` **how can I reolize it?**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import { AsyncStorage, Text, View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

class AsyncStorageExample extends Component {
   state = {
      'name': ''
   }
   componentDidMount = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then((value) => this.setState({ 'name': value }))
   
   setName = (value) => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('name', value);
      this.setState({ 'name': value });
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>
            <TextInput style = {styles.textInput} autoCapitalize = 'none'
            onChangeText = {this.setName}/>
            <Text>
               {this.state.name}
            </Text>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default AsyncStorageExample

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 50
   },
   textInput: {
      margin: 5,
      height: 100,
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#7685ed'
   }
})
```

Comment: Are you want to save object into AsyncStorage on button click????

Comment: Yes, that is, inside the input, a text was entered for example "Alex" and an object named Alext was formed inside the state in this way this.state = { users: [ {id: 1, name: 'Alex'} ] }

Answer (score 0):

You can check following code it will help to solve your problem.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";

class AsyncStorageExample extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    savedData: "",
  };
  componentDidMount = () =>
    AsyncStorage.getItem("name").then((value) =>
      this.setState({ savedData: value })
    );

  setData = (value) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify([{ id: 1, name: value }]));
  };
  getData = (value) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("name").then((value) =>
      this.setState({ savedData: value })
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChangeText={(value) => {
            this.setData(value);
          }}
        />
        <Text>{this.state.savedData}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setData(this.state.name);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.saveButton}>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{"Save Data"}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          onPress={() => {
            this.getData(this.state.name);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.saveButton}>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{"Get Data"}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default AsyncStorageExample;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  saveButton: {
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    marginBottom:10,
    marginTop:15,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderColor: "white",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: "#7685ed",
  },
  textInput: {
    width: "80%",
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#7685ed",
  },
});
```

Comment: but you can make it so that when you click on the "Get data" button, it automatically synchronizes, that is, do not click on the save data button?

Comment: It means you want to save data on text change without click on save data. right??

Comment: Please check i have updated my code now without click on save button data automatically sync.

Comment: I am deeply grateful for your help, but unfortunately I have a slightly different problem, I cannot explain in words if you do not mind, I would like to demonstrate my code using a screencast or using teamviewer

Comment: Sorry but right now I M away from home and so i am unable to access system.